# Pandas crosstab on DataFrame 1-dimension error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compute group frequencies using this multi-indexed DataFrame:

```
In [1]: frame
Out[1]:
                    position      values
idmajor  idminor
  22        2           6           A
   4        1           7           B
  11        1           7           C
  23        1           7           B
   1        1           8           C
            9           8           C
   4        1           8           C
            1           8           C
```

Here is my code and error:

```
In [2]: pd.crosstab(frame.position, frame.values)
Out[2]: Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Here is what I am trying to output:

```
Out[2]:
   categories    A       B       C
   values
   6             1       0       0
   7             0       2       1
   8             0       0       4
```

I'm reading through *Python for Data Analysis* and have just started with the `pandas` library. I am struggling to find answers or examples that will give me a greater understanding to this problem. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Due to the multi-index of the DataFrame I was misled by the Exception. The multi-index nature of this frame has nothing to do with the Exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the documentation, [pd.DataFrame.values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) is reserved through *pandas* in the Python namespace so I was referencing a function of my data column and not a column label like I thought I was!

The dot notation `pd.crosstab(frame.position, frame.values)` returns the error `Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional` whereas the dictionary notation `pd.crosstab(frame['position'], frame['values'])` returns success!

```
In [2]: pd.crosstab(frame['position'], frame['values'])
Out[2]:
categories    A       B       C
values
6             1       0       0
7             0       2       1
8             0       0       4
```

To avoid future confusion my solution and answer will be to just change the name of my DataFrame column `values` to `categories`.

Comment: @unutbu, thanks for the edit. I've been staring at this one for too long.

Comment: You might want to avoid the dot notation for column names entirely. It requires more mental horsepower -- too much IMHO -- to have to check if a column name happens to be a Python keyword, or predefined DataFrame attribute. For example, you can not use `df.from`, `df.as`, `df.class`, `df.yield` since these attribute names are Python keywords. You also can't access column names with spaces using the dot notation. Sure, it requires a bit more typing, but if you use `df['colname']` exclusively, you never have to worry about this.